# How to clear a _setVar custom variable from session in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-analytics

I'm currently tracking an eCommerce site that has both a main version and a mobile version. I need to be able to track these two sites separately, but in the same property so I can also see the combined data.

The mobile version lives in a subdirectory of the main site, but it shares the same checkout  and confirmation pages as the main site (same URL, different header and styling). Because of this, I'm not able to simply filter the two "views" for each site by include/exclude subdirectory. Instead I decided to use a user-defined filter via a "_setVar" variable, where the pages on the mobile site would send a var named "Mobile".

I then setup a filter for the "Mobile Site" view in my GA account to include only when the "Mobile" variable is present, and the "Main Site" view to exclude when "Mobile" is present. This seems to be working well for tracking pageviews and events.

The problem is with tracking transactions. If a visitor hits the site on a mobile device, they will be served the mobile version. If that visitor then decides to view the full site (by clicking the "View Full Site" link) and then places an order on the Main site, the transaction still records on the "Mobile Site" view instead of the "Main Site" view.

Are "_setVar" variables "sessionized"? Could this be why the transaction is incorrectly recorded to the "Mobile Site" view? Is there a way to clear this var from the session so the transactions no longer carry the "Mobile" var?

I'd really appreciate any info or advice on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could `_setVar` to `Switched to Desktop`+ fire an event onclick of the "switch to desktop" link. Or use [`_deleteCustomVar`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._deleteCustomVar)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after getting a better understanding of how _setVar really works. It was quite simple then really:

Set _setVar = 'Mobile' for all hits to the mobile site, then set _setVar = 'Main' for all hits to the main site. _setVar is only capable of storing a single value so it simply overwrites the previous value and thus, only reports the hit for the current site being viewed.

Then I just had to tweak the filter of the "Main Site" to include user defined value of 'Main'.